# jQuery append inside for loop

Tags: jquery

I have a particular problem which I dont seem to wrap around my head. I am using reddit api to get the data.

**UPDATED**

```
$(function() {

  console.log("is it loading")

  axios.get('http://www.reddit.com/r/DrunkOrAKid/hot.json?sort=hot')
  .then(function(data){
    var q;
    for(var i = 2; i < data.data.data.children.length; i++){
      q = data.data.data.children[i];
      $('#main').append('<h4>' + q.data.title + '</h4><br><button class="btn btn-success trigger">answer</button><div class="answer">'+ q.data.selftext +'</div>')


      $('.answer').hide()


      $('.trigger').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log("clicked", [i]);
        $('.answer').show()
      })
    }
  }).catch(function(error){
    console.log("error occured")
  })
})
```

So basically I wanted to show the answer using #trigger. But the problem lies when I clicked the #trigger button, the array shows 27 count rather than the actual  count which is 26. It somehow added one count when I click #trigger button. Right now I cannot managed to click the button to show the answer. Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Why are you appending variables to strings with `[variable]`?  That's creating an unnecessary array.  Also you should really consider using classes for these fields instead of making an id that is enumerated.  You can then select the class and get the `eq(index)` of them to work with.

Comment: I've change to class already it does'nt seem to work. I'm not really sure what you meant in the first question. I'm appending [i] to my id because I wanted each button & answer to have different id from each other. Currently there are 26 index inside my array so there are 26 buttons and answers. and when I click for example the third index button, it should only show me the third answer.

Comment: [] outside of a string is an array.  Typically you do not concatenate an array to a string.  Were you trying to make the id follow the pattern of `name[#]` ?  In any case with a class you do not need any of that.  Can you update your question with the new logic and what is not working?

Comment: Yeah. I'm trying to concatenate my index to my id. So lets say the fifth button should have an id like this `<button id="trigger3></button>`. It works when I open up my dev tools. The problem seems to be on the click function.

Comment: I've edited my code. But the problem now is that when i click the first button it will show all of the answer. What I want is to just show the first answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and see.  It's not doing lookups.  It's using/bind on the elements as it makes them.  A better approach might be to use a delegated listener with contextual lookups.

```
    axios.get('http://www.reddit.com/r/DrunkOrAKid/hot.json?sort=hot')
        .then(function(data) {
            var $main = $('#main');

            //use slice so you can use forEach instead of rolling your own for loop
            data.data.data.children.slice(2).forEach(function(child){
                //instead of looking up trigger, create it so you can do whatever you want with it
                var $trigger = $('<button class="btn btn-success">answer</button>');
                //same with answer
                var $answer = $('<div class="answer">'+ child.data.selftext +'</div>');

                $answer.hide();

                $trigger.on('click', function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $answer.show();
                });

                $main
                    .append('<h4>'+ child.data.title +'</h4><br>')
                    .append($trigger)
                    .append($answer);
            });
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log("error occured")
        });
    });
```

Comment: Yeah it works. Thanks. Can you clarify why I need to use forEach rather than for loop? What are the difference between the two? Another one is what is the rationale in putting the append at the end rather than my approach? and what is lookups? I'm trying to really understand the logic rather than just copy paste. Thanks for the answer again.

Comment: forEach is a bit cleaner than for since you don't have to keep track of index and such.  They both do the same logic, but forEach does alot of the boilerplating.  The order of appending and binding really doesn't matter.  Though you'd probably want to do the hide() before the append because append is going to do a browser redraw, and so will hide/show.  If you hide before it is attached to the page, there is no redraw.  So 1 redraw vs 2.  $(selector) is a lookup, provided the selector is a string and not a function/object.